# Dynamic Call <T> object class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

How can I dynamically pass the class? (EDIT)
call with name string =(

I want to pass A1 or A2 to the getData function

Any ideas or references to support me?

```
public class A1{
   public int dataA1 {get;set;}
}

public class A2{
   public int dataA2 {get;set;}
}

Type obj= Type.GetType("A2");;

var example = GetData<obj>();

public void GetData<T>(){
   //process T custom (A1 or A2) T = A2
}
```

Comment: There needs to be some similarity between A1 and A2, like a common base class or an interface.

Comment: I would use a common interface.

Comment: could you elaborate on this point: "//process T custom (A1 or A2)" the answers might differ strongly in this respect

Comment: please correct the return type of `GetData`, otherwise `var example = GetData<A1 or A2>();` does not make any sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should declare a base class, `ABase` (or with a better name) and then use this as the basis for your generic processing:

```
public class ABase
{
    public int data { get; set; }
}

public class A1 : ABase {
    ... implementation that presumably sets data
}

public class A2 : ABase {
    ... implementation that presumably sets data
}

var example = GetData<ABase>();

public void GetData<T>() where T : ABase {
   // Do something with T which can be A1 or A2 but supports GetData
}
```

In `GetData<T>`, you can now guarantee that the `data` property is accessible on both `A1` and `A2` because it is declared on the base class `ABase`.

Alternatively, you could implement an interface that defined the property:

```
public interface IBase
{
    int data { get; set; }
}

public class A1 : IBase {
    // Implement the interface here
    public int data { get; set; }
}

...
```

**Edit following @AnuViswan Comment**

As Any Viswan has pointed out, in your example (and therefore mine), `GetData<T>` does not return anything, but `var example` is set to the result of the method.

This is no doubt a typo in your example.  I'm guessing that `GetData<T>` should return an `int`.

Comment: GetData<A1>() or GetData<A2>() would have better demonstrated the answer rather than GetData<ABase>(). Also, please note the method is void. So the assignment operator is wrong.

Comment: @AnuViswan Thank you, I have added a note about that to the answer to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Using an interface (or an abstract class). In this way you just use the common parent.

```
    public interface IA
    {
        public int Data { get; set; }
    } 

    public class A1 : IA
    {
        public int Data { get; set; }
        public A1(int data) => Data = data * 12;
    }

    public class A2 : IA
    {
        public int Data { get; set; }
        public A1(int data) => Data = data / 144;
    }

    public int GetData(IA a) => return a.Data;

    GetData(new A1(1));     // -> 12
    GetData(new A2(144));   // -> 1
```